# Pathname expansion with multiple criteria in Bash

Tags: bash

Suppose that there are these files in my directory:

```
a1x
albtmk
axxxxx
blabla
bb
```

I would like to use `ls` based on some criteria and then print the output using `echo`. Criteria are:

1. File name has three and more characters,
2. file name starts on vowel,
3. penultimate character is not a number.

So, desired output is `albtmk axxxxx`.

What I tried so far:

```
MYFILES=`ls a??* e??* i??* o??* u??* y??* A??* E??* I??* O??* U??* Y??*`

echo $MYFILES
```

I would like to ask:

1. Can I combine `a??* e??* i??* o??* u??* y??* A??* E??* I??* O??* U??* Y??*` together?
2. How can I form the condition *penultimate character is not a number* ? Somehow using regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you don't need regular expressions here.

```
ls [AEIOUYaeiouy]*[!0-9]?
```

Answer (score 4):

With bash:

- You can use a case-insensitive globbing pattern.
- Store the list of files matching the pattern into an array.
- Print the array elements into a space-delimited list.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Query and save nocaseglob state
shopt -q nocaseglob && nocaseglob=1

# Make globbing patterns expands case insensitively
shopt -s nocaseglob

# Populate the myfiles array with all files matching the pattern
myfiles=( [aeiouy]*[!0-9]? )

# Restore nocaseglob state
[ "$nocaseglob" ] || shopt -u nocaseglob

# Print all myfiles entries in the same line:
printf %s\\n "${myfiles[*]}"
```

---

Note from [inian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5291015/inian):

> saving `nocaseglob` status and restoring is needed only if the script needs to be sourced. For a normal executed shell script, it isn't required.

Answer (score 0):

Use `find` with regular expressions:

```
find . -regex '\./[aeiouyAEIOUY].*[^0-9].$'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However your solution inserts `./` before the file name, which is not a desired output.